# Devise user#skip_confirmation_notification! not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to change the user's password following this link: [Allow-users-to-edit-their-password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password). I've added `skip_confirmation_notification` to `user` to avoid confirmation email but it doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
def update_password
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.skip_confirmation_notification!
    if @user.update(user_password_params)
      flash.notice = 'Password was successfully updated.'
    else
      flash.alert = @user.errors.full_messages.join('<br/>')
    end
    render "show_update_password"
end

private

def user_password_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For updates you can stick with update_attributes, or just a plain save and `skip_reconfirmation!` (note the 're' in reconfirmation).

```
def update_password
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.skip_reconfirmation!
  if @user.update(user_password_params)
     flash.notice = 'Password was successfully updated.'
  else
     flash.alert = @user.errror.full_messages.join('<br/>')
  end
  render "show_update_password"
end
```

Check here for Device Documentation [Doc](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/Confirmable:skip_reconfirmation%21)